# Demostrating possible equivalence of two tensors

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Is there anyway to see by inspection that a form like 
$$a(x^2 )^{-3} (g _{μσ} x_{\rho} x_{ ν}  + g_{μρ} x_{σ} x_{ ν} +g_{νσ} x_{ρ} x_{ μ} + g_{ νρ} x_{ σ} x_{ μ} ) $$
may be equivalent to (i.e reduced down to or reexpressed) $$
b(g _{μν} x_{ ρ} x_{ σ} + g_{ ρσ} x_{ μ} x_{ ν} )(x^2 )^{ −3} ?$$ where $g_{\mu \nu}$ is the metric tensor (diagonal).

I have tried to put in various permutations of $\mu \nu \rho \sigma$ and from $1111$ and $2222$ for example, I obtained the constraint that $a/b = 2$ but I am not really sure what this means.  If I try the combination $1221$ e.g then it implies $b=0$, which seems to contradict my first result.

Does this mean that the two forms are not equivalent?

Comment: Yes. If you obtain contradicting contraints for the forms to be equivalent, then, assuming you made no computational error, this implies the forms are not equivalent.

Comment: @ACuriousMind The permutation $1111$ yields the constraint $2a=b$ and so does the permutation $1112$ but $1221$ gives $a=0$, which means $b$ would have to be zero from the first constraint. What am I to make of this?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I was hoping they would be equivalent :) Are you familiar with Di Francesco's book on CFT? On P.108, he writes a general form for a tensor but I don't see why he neglects the equation above with four terms? I thought he did it because of the equivalence with one of the others, but this is now not the case.

Comment: Hm, that sounds weird, but I'm not familiar with his book, I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway. Yeah, it is not the first time I have found mistakes in his book, I'll check with one of my professors, thanks ;)

Comment: I made another thread, but it doesn't seem to be attracting a lot of attention. Do you think it would be okay to contact the author about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, if no values of $a$ and $b$ work for across different sets of indices, then the forms are not equivalent.

In fact, these two forms are not equivalent even under the restriction of the metric being diagonal (and thus are not equivalent under a general metric). The diagonal case is easy to analyze, and you gave a good set of indices to do it: $\mu\nu\rho\sigma = 1221$. Then the large parenthesized part of the first expression becomes $g_{11} x_2 x_2 + g_{22} x_1 x_1$. The middle terms drop out because they involve off-diagonal parts of the metric. However, both terms in the second expression also involve off-diagonal metric coefficients, so the second expression is identically $0$.

Given tensor components $T_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ and $S_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$, we have $T_{1221} = g_{11} x_2 x_2 + g_{22} x_1 x_1$ while $S_{1221} = 0$, so clearly $T \not\propto S$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Are you familiar with Di Francesco's book on Conformal field theory at all?